# How to fix errors running apt-get?

Tags: apt, dpkg

A while ago updates stopped working. Now, when running `apt-get`, I get the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglu1-mesa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: output http://pastebin.com/xcKLrFgV

Also, running Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: can you pastebin.com the entire trace of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as well as `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` - thanks.

Comment: It would help to see the results requested by fossfreedom. You could try sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as well as cat `/etc/apt/sources.list` output added.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with a segmentation fault in the package, or within apt.  Does this happen with any other packages?

Comment: Have you tried to install `libgl1-mesa-glx` before installing `libglu1-mesa`? Somethink like: `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx && sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa`

Comment: @BSeven - what graphics card and graphics drivers have you got installed?  How did you install your graphics drivers?  What happens if you remove those graphics drivers and just run with the opensource drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours and hours trying to fix it and Googling, I reinstalled the OS off the installation CD I burned. I think that took only 15 minutes.

So, the lesson is to keep all you data on a separate partition. I probably don't need any updates anyway because 11.04 works fine the way it is. The entire OS only uses 4GB, so a 64GB SSD with 2 partitions works great.